# SSRS calendar date/time parameter issue

Tags: reporting-services

I have @start and @ end date parameter in ssrs running the report does not show today date report I have date/time in my ssms query. when I run the query i see the data with today date.Any Idea?

Comment: You need to add more info, such as the datatypes you are querying, are they dates, datetimes etc? Show your dataset query or wherever your report parameters are being used so we can see what you are trying. However, my guess is that you will need to cast both sides of the comparison to date. e.g. `WHERE CAST(myDateColumn as Date) BETWEEN CAST(@StartDate as Date) AND CAST(@EndDate as Date)`

Comment: Does your date contain a time value? If you are filtering on `<= @EndDate` then any row on the end date that has a time value will be filtered out. You may need to truncate off the time component before making the comparison.